# How to include generated docs into main documentation in Diplodoc?

Tags: diplodoc

We have multiple projects, some of them are in cpp, part in java and python.
There are couple of rules which we are following for creation of APIs and a rule of thumb is that we use docstrings population which can be gathered into documentation automatically.

We are using Open API spec and JavaDoc mostly.

Does Diplodoc support inclusion of those generated docs into main documentation?

I've tried to include JavaDoc "as is" but it's ugly and with own formatting and css.
We'd like to have something that looks better when included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, Diplodoc supports OpenAPI specification natively and it can included into your main documentation.
As for the JavaDoc, you can use custom includer as described on https://ydocs.tech/en/project/toc#includers-generic